# Как сделать график на javascript, чтобы на каждой высоте был свой цвет? (Как на картинке)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, диаграммы

[image]

Пишу приложение для `vk` на `React.js`, и мне нужен график, как на картинке.

Как сделать такое разделение цветов по высоте? Пробовал использовать библиотеку `React-Vis`, но не получилось.

Comment: Попробуй использовать [react-charts](https://react-charts.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю @Leviathan_ZC, проще всего воспользоваться готовой библиотекой [react-charts](https://react-charts.js.org/).

Если же хотите всё сделать сами, то изучайте [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).